# Implement google routes api through gRPC request in golang

Tags: go, google-maps, grpc

I am beginner in grpc. I want to request google routes API through grpc. I am aware of the client library google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/maps/routes/v1 but it is not in stable version. Hence, I am creating a custom function.

Here is my proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package google.maps.routing.v2;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
// import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
// import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";


// The Routes API.
service Routes {
  rpc ComputeRouteMatrix(ComputeRouteMatrixRequest)
      returns (stream RouteMatrixElement) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/routes.googleapis.com/distanceMatrix/v2:computeRouteMatrix"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}


 /* Messages */
message ComputeRouteMatrixRequest{
    repeated RouteMatrixOrigin origins=1;
    repeated RouteMatrixDestinations destinations=2;
}

message RouteMatrixOrigin{
    Waypoint waypoint=1;
}
message Waypoint{
    Location location=1;
}
message Location{
    Latlng latLng=1;
}
message Latlng{
    float latitude=1;
    float longitude=2;
}

message RouteMatrixDestinations{
    Waypoint waypoint=1;
}

message RouteMatrixElement{
    int32 distanceMeters=1;
    string duration=2;
    int32 originIndex=3;
    int32 destinationIndex=4;
}

message Status{
    int32 code =1;
    string message=2;
}
```

I am facing a panic :

```
panic: proto: file "routing/routing.proto" has a name conflict over google.maps.routing.v2.RouteMatrixElement
    previously from: "cloud.google.com/go/maps/routing/apiv2/routingpb"
    currently from:  "bkgrpc/proto/routing"
See https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict


goroutine 1 [running]:
google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.glob..func1({0x1e37ca0?, 0xc00013eb60?}, {0x1e37ca0?, 0xc00013eba0})
```

Can anyone please help me in creating the server file.

Comment: See https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict